# How to make different categories view from one php file

Tags: php, mysql

My title might seems unclear. I will describe what I want to do.Let's say the picture shown below is my index.php. If I click 0-100 in 'Select by price', it redirects me to another php file. The difference between this index.php and the '0-100' is just a mysql query that shows different products according to the price in the products box and same for all the others too. Now I realize that it is not a good way to do. And I tried to google my problem but as I am new in PHP i could not find the exact technological name to search in internet. Could you please help me how can I solve my problem or please share the link like my problem.  [image: index.php]

Comment: Are you after pagination ?

Comment: Yeah. I have pagination but what is after pagination?

Comment: All this should be piped through one index.php file with get variables to change the internal logic and/or sql queries. To flip between files like that is pointless, as it'll just lead to code duplication as they'll be doing almost identical things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** One way would be to use php [get variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm) in the php file, and echo items if price lies between the variable value.

Your url would be something like`index.php?low=0&high=100`.

This gives you two variables, the lower limit on price and the higher limit on price.

While echoing the product you can check for condition,

```
if($price>=$_GET['low'] && $price<=$_GET['high']){
     //then only show the item.
}
```

**2.** Another way would be to use **javascript** or **jquery**.

Where you can iterate over items and hide them if they do not belong to selected range client side itself. Hence, the page will have to be reloaded if user changes the price ranges.

Comment: Ok I want to refresh myself. Let's say I have leftside.php. There I have those four price categories, o-100, 100-200 etc in one div. in there, should I make a link this way?  
 <li class="list"><a href="index.php_low=0&high=100">0 - 100</a></li>

Comment: Please go through the link I have given in the answer. It should be `<a href="index.php?low=0&high=100">`

Comment: Yeah I meant like that way. Actually the answer appeared lately. This makes sense to me. I will give it a try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'switch', very basic solution:

```
<a href="index.php?price_from=0&price_to=100">Click</a>

<?php

if(!isset($_GET['price_from']) && !isset($_GET['price_to']))

{
```

redirect to index or something

```
}

switch($_GET['price_from'].'-'.$_GET['price_to'])

{

   case '0-100':

      echo 'Your content';          

      break;

   case '100-300':

      echo 'Your content';

      break;

   case '300-500':

      echo 'Your content';

      break;

   default:

      load index or something

}
```

Comment: Thanks dude!! Make sense to me. I give it a try :)